How to get arguments of linux kernel functions with kprobe
I was playing with kernel modules in Linux and based on examples on https://sysprog21.github.io/lkmpg/ I found a nice example to use kprobes to hook own functions to internal kernel functions which seems to work nicely.
I wanted to get the arguments of the called function, Since my system is a X86_64 system the call convention should be that the arguments should be in registers RDI, RSI and RDX (in that order).
The registered callback function (pre_handler) has an regs argument which contains the registers di, si and dx. I assume that these are the saved rdi, rsi and rdx registers since all these fields in the pr_regs structure are 64 bit.
The function I used to hook my pre-handler is
__x64_sys_openat(int dfd, const char *path, struct open_how *how)

I would expect the first argument as a small positive integer, the 2nd and 3th arg as a pointer.
What I see in the output of my module:
[23374.116347] "pre 1st arg dfd  :" [di]:  0xFFFFAE19081A3F58 (-90052443357352) valid 0
[23374.116351] "pre 2nd arg *path:" [si]:  0x101 (257) valid 0
[23374.116353] "pre 3th arg *how :" [dx]:  0x0 (0) valid 0

The 1st argument looks like an address(pointer), the 2nd as an integer value  and the last could be a nullpointer, which could be valid.
If I try to print the second argument as a string (obviously) a kernel crash occurs.
Can I retrieve the contents of the arguments from the saved registers in the pt_regs struct ? And can you explain me why this doesn't work ?
I use Fedora linux: uname output:
Linux 6.11.10-200.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Nov 23 00:53:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The code I used:
/* 
 * syscall-steal.c 
 * 
 * System call "stealing" sample. 
 * 
 * Disables page protection at a processor level by changing the 16th bit 
 * in the cr0 register (could be Intel specific). 
 */ 
 
#include <linux/delay.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/moduleparam.h> /* which will have params */ 
#include <linux/unistd.h> /* The list of system calls */ 
#include <linux/cred.h> /* For current_uid() */ 
#include <linux/uidgid.h> /* For __kuid_val() */ 
#include <linux/version.h> 
 
/* For the current (process) structure, we need this to know who the 
 * current user is. 
 */ 
#include <linux/sched.h> 
#include <linux/uaccess.h> 
 
/* If you have tried to use the syscall table to intercept syscalls and it  
* doesn't work, you can try to use Kprobes to intercept syscalls. 
* Set USE_KPROBES_PRE_HANDLER_BEFORE_SYSCALL to 1 to register a pre-handler 
* before the syscall. 
*/ 
#include <linux/kprobes.h> 

#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE  1024

/* UID we want to spy on - will be filled from the command line. */ 
static uid_t uid = -1; 
module_param(uid, int, 0644); 
 
/*
 * rdi: 1st argument (saved in regs->di?)
 * rsi: 2nd argument (saved in regs->si?)
 * rdx: 3th argument (saved in regs->dx?)
 *
 * __x64_sys_openat(int dfd, const char *path, struct open_how *how)
 * dfd  => rdi
 * path => rsi
 * how  => rdx
 * 
 */

#define VALID_ADDRESS(desc, name) pr_info("%s [%s]:  0x%lX (%ld) valid %d\n", #desc, #name, regs->name, regs->name, virt_addr_valid(regs->name)); 

static int openat_pre_handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs) 
{ 
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];

    if (__kuid_val(current_uid()) != uid) { 
        return 0; 
    }  
    strcpy(filename, "No file"); 
    pr_info("openat called by %d\n", uid); 
    VALID_ADDRESS("pre 1st arg dfd  :", di);
    VALID_ADDRESS("pre 2nd arg *path:", si);
    VALID_ADDRESS("pre 3th arg *how :", dx);
    if(copy_from_user(filename, (void*)regs->si, MAX_FILENAME_SIZE-1)) {
        pr_info("copy user data failed\n");
    }
    pr_info("Opening file: %s\n", filename);
    //dump_stack();
    return 0; 
}


static struct kprobe openat_kprobe = { 
    .symbol_name = "__x64_sys_openat", 
    .pre_handler = openat_pre_handler, 
}; 

static int __init syscall_steal_start(void) 
{ 
    pr_info("Using kprobes\n");

    int err;
    err = register_kprobe(&openat_kprobe);
    if (err) {
        pr_err("register_kprobe() on openat failed: %d\n", err); 
    } 
    return err;
    
    pr_info("Spying on UID:%d\n", uid); 
    
    return err; 
} 
 
static void __exit syscall_steal_end(void) 
{ 
    unregister_kprobe(&openat_kprobe); 
    msleep(500); 
} 
 
module_init(syscall_steal_start); 
module_exit(syscall_steal_end); 
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


__x64_sys_openat(int dfd, const char *path, struct open_how *how) - No, the wrapper __x64_sys_openat accepts single struct pt_regs * argument, which it expands to parameters for C function sys_openat. Since you are using kprobe, you need to expand struct pt_regs * twice, not once.

Indeed, casting the di field of the pt_regs to a pt_regs and using these register fields solves my issue. @Tsyvarev Thanks for pointing out. I have learned something new today.
